# React rerendering - misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, virtual-dom

I thought React was just reloading the things I needed - in my case it looks different or I've done something wrong.

I have table of employees. For each employee in single day I can set start and end of work time. Like this:

```
const ScheduleRow = React.memo((props) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            // number of row - doesn't matter
            <th className="text-center">{ props.no }</th>
            { ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04" /* etc */ ].map(
                date => { return (
                    <ScheduleCell date={ date } employee_id={ props.employee_id }/>
                )}) }
        </tr>
    )
})

const ScheduleCell = React.memo((props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    let schedule_id = `${props.employee_id}:${props.date}`
    const schedule = useSelector(state => state.schedules)[schedule_id] || null

    /* some code here - not changing state */

    console.log(props.date)

    return (
        <td>
            <Form.Control type="text" value={schedule?.begin}
                onChange={(e) => dispatch({
                    type: "EDIT_SCHEDULE",
                    schedule_id: schedule_id,
                    property: "begin",
                    value: e.target.value
                })}/>
            <Form.Control type="text" value={schedule?.cease}
                onChange={(e) => dispatch({
                    type: "EDIT_SCHEDULE",
                    schedule_id: schedule_id,
                    property: "cease",
                    value: e.target.value
                })}/>
        </td>
    )
});
```

You can see that I have console.log() in ScheduleCell before return which prints date of day which is editing. I belive that when I change cell ( e.g date "2020-01-02" ) I should see only  "2020-01-02" in console. But I see every dates from array in ScheduleRow it's mean that React modify every cells even if I changed only one cell.

What is wrong with my reasoning and how can improve it to reload only editing cell ?

Comment: You're missing a `key` props at least on the `ScheduleCell` rendering inside or the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you add a proper `key` prop to your `<ScheduleCell/>` elements. Without this, React won't correlate that the same component instance should be reused on re-render. Same goes for whatever renders `<ScheduleRow/>`.

```
const ScheduleRow = React.memo((props) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <th className="text-center">{ props.no }</th> // number of row - doesn't matter
            { ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04" /* etc */ ].map(date => { return (
                <ScheduleCell key={ date } date={ date } employee_id={ props.employee_id }/>
            )}) }
        </tr>
    )
})
```

`React.memo` only memoizes the output *within the context of a component instance* if the props are the same as the last time that instance rendered. For more on how this works, read up on React's [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

Comment: The `key={}` prop needs to be unique, so if your date list is going to contain dups, make sure you use something else.

Comment: Note that it only needs to be unique within its parent; in this case I'm guessing `<ScheduleRow/>` elements are also created using something like `.map(...)`; if so, they'll also need unique keys. For example, if each row is unique per employee ID, then that would be a good key. If each schedule cell is unique per employee per date, then date would be a fine key since the uniqueness per employee is already taken care of in the parent.

Comment: I added unique key for every Component which console told me to change but nothing change.

Comment: Is your key unique but also _identifying_ and _consistent_? Just using a unique key will get rid of the warning, but unless it's also those other two things, you won't get component reuse.

Comment: For my ScheduleRow I have `row-${employe_id}` and for ScheduleCell I have `cell-${schedule_id}`. Is it enough?

Comment: Should be fine; maybe you're missing some other important detail in your post that could explain the issue.

Comment: Is it posible that reason is that each cell have data from schedules reducer which is associative array of schedules ? Example ` { "1:2020-01-01" : { begin: "16:20", cease: "20:30", etc }`

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.f7d60d7b182045748d13c88bdace6049

Comment: Yes, if they're unique objects each time and they're being passed as props, that'd cause a re-render. You may have to be more surgical with what you pass to your components.

Comment: I will try to change it to use inner state and only pass data to reducer. I will let you know about result tomorrow.